# creating directories on smb share through php script

Tags: php, mkdir, smb

I'm using http://www.smorgasbork.com/2008/07/23/accessing-smb-servers-with-php/ smbclient stream wrapper in my script.

I am able to create a directory on a share with this code:

```
<?php
require('smbclient.php');
$smbc = new smbclient ('//servername/public','d\username','password');
    if (!$smbc->mkdir ("a"))
        {
        echo "failure";
        print join ("\n", $smbc->get_last_cmd_stdout());
        }
        else {
        echo "success";
        }
?>
```

Now What i can't figure out if how to create the directory under this path:
//servername/public/already/existing/file/structure/a

If i'm using smbclient normally i just cd to the directory in which i want to modify something sadly thats not an option because theres no cd function in smbclient.php

Comment: If somone wonders i found the solution myself. The problem was that i took /already/existing/file/structure/a as path. Now without the first / it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Just out of interest, did you get this to be able to read files?

Comment: @MattCowley If i remember correctly i used it to create and delete directories and modify ACL.